# What is the difference between enrichment media and selective media?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, cell-culture

> #### Enrichment media
>
> These media are used to suppress commensal bacteria while allowing the pathogen to remain viable and grow.
>
> [Source: Ananthnarayan and Paniker's textbook of Microbiology.]

There is also an example of tetrathionate broth as enrichment media given in the book where tetrathionate inhibits coliforms while allowing typhoid-paratyphoid bacilli to grow.

For selective media it writes:

> As in the above case (of enrichment media), if inhibiting substance is added to a solid medium, it enables a greater number of the required bacterium to form colonies than the other bacteria.

For this selective media an example of Deoxycholate Citrate Agar (DCA) for fecal samples is given.

### The question:

What's the difference between enrichment media and selective media? [Some answers](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-enrichment-medium-and-selective-medium) give quite contradictory statements to the statement of the book like stating that "...it is designed to stimulate growth of many different types of bacterial species" for enrichment media.

I am also not able to explain myself as to how selective medium enables a greater number of the required bacterium to form colonies than other bacteria since inhibitory substance is also present in enrichment media?